# Get all the permissions in (/admin/people/permissions)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

is there any drupal 7 function can list all the permissions in the system (/admin/people/permissions)
like this ( user_permission_get_modules() )

i'm trying to create a drupal module ,what i need is to get all the permissions and add each one of the list in a checked box list and please if there is any possibility to make the value of the checked box the same as the column 'permission' in the table 'role_permission'.

thanks in advance ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to just reuse the built-in permissions form.

```
$form = drupal_get_form('user_admin_permissions');
```

If you need to alter the form for your purposes, you can do so after retrieving it with the code above. I recommend using the [`dpm`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) function from the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to analyze the form and see what changes you need to make to it.